# How to transform selected text to lowercase in PHPStorm?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, lowercase

There is `Ctrl + Shift + U` shortcut, but it toggles characters case while I need to make all of selected characters in lowercase.

Comment: Hmm ... works for me: `N4tuPqeY` --> `n4tupqey` --> `N4TUPQEY` --> `n4tupqey`

Comment: Yes, as @LazyOne has stated, that shortcut should be sufficient. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Toggling_Case.html

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Other way. Select text. Hit <kbd>Ctrl+shift+a</kbd> type 'toggle  case` and hit selected action
[image: toggle case action]

Comment: This is just the same as using `Ctrl + Shift + U`, isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

For phpStorm 2020 on MAC:

`Shift + Command + U`

Check out in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Toggling_Case.html

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl+shift+a</kbd> works again at least in PHPStorm 2017.2.4